# Using JAR from HUE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, impala, hue

I have jar file that get IP as param and return csv:

```
Country,Organization
```

I.e `myjar.jar 8.8.8.8` will return

```
Country,Organization
United States,Google
```

I have Hadoop table with IP address, I want to call to my JAR with IP from my table and to get the results from my JAR, Is is possible?

I'm using HUE with Hive/Impala editor and did:

```
add jar HDFS:///PATH/TO/MY/JAR.JAR
```

And now I don't know how to use my jar

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to write a UDF to be able to call it from Hive. https://blog.dataiku.com/2013/05/01/a-complete-guide-to-writing-hive-udf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say which class within the JAR to use by defining a function.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION name AS 'com.example.full.class.name'
```

Then use `name()` as a SQL function

Comment: And How should my class should define? I need to extends from UDF or something like that?

Comment: That's right. You can find various examples of this online